# How to autorotate pdflscape landscape pages when n-upping

Tags: pdf, pdflscape

I'm using `pdflscape` for my landscape pages in an A5 portrait document. Then I use the following command line to prepare the PDF to be printed on A4 paper:

```
pdftk blank.pdf document.pdf output padded_document.pdf verbose && pdfnup --paper a4paper padded_document.pdf
```

The resulting `padded_document-nup.pdf`, however, has all the landscape pages still in landscape in what amounts to an A6 format, instead of having them rotated and in A5.

Is there a way to automatically rotate them so they will appear in the intended size? I know I could replace `pdflscape` by `lscape` but I keep forgetting that and it'd be nice to have a solution that doesn't involve changing my document each time I want to print it. So either a clever trick in the PDF or something I can put in my command line.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\blindtext
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Landscape figure}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\blindtext\blindtext

\blindtext\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Which as 4-up with page borders (not the desired 2-up without borders but you get the idea) looks like this:

[image: 3 portrait, 1 landscape]

What it *should* look like is this:

[image: 4 portrait]
I faked this last one by just using `lscape` instead of `pdflscape`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pdfnup` uses `pdfjam`, which in turn uses the LaTeX package `pdfpages`. The latter one knows the option `rotateoversize`, from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf):

> This option allows to rotate oversized pages. E.g. pages in landscape
>   orientation are oversized relatively to their portrait counter- part,
>   because they do not match within the contour of a portrait page
>   without rotating them. By default oversized pages are scale and are
>   not rotated. Either `true` or `false` (or no value, which is
>   equivalent to `true`). (Default: `rotateoversize=false`)

This option can be specified on the command line for `pdfnup` or `pdfjam`:

```bash
$ pdfnup --paper a4paper --rotateoversize true test.pdf
```

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

[image: 2xA5 on A4]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{my 2up}
{
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=2,%
    physical height=\paperwidth,%
    physical width=\paperheight,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{my 2up}[a4paper]
\begin{document}
  \blindtext\blindtext
  \begin{landscape}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{Landscape figure}
    \end{figure}
  \end{landscape}
  \blindtext\blindtext

  \blindtext\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be more usefull than the other one.
You can convert A4 or A5 (one unique size for the input file), landscape or portrait (one orientation for the input file) to a A4 format file constitued of two A5 merged and landscape oriented pages per page.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'

FILE_EXT=$(echo "$1" | cut -f2 -d '.')

# Vérifier si fichier pdf
if [ "$FILE_EXT" != pdf ]
then
echo "Attention, le fichier $1 n'est pas un fichier .pdf"
exit
fi

FILE_NAME=$(echo "$1" | cut -f1 -d '.')

# Détecter la présence du fichier en .pdf
if [ ! -e "./$FILE_NAME.pdf" ]
then
echo "Attention, le fichier $FILE_NAME.pdf n'existe pas"
exit
fi

X=$(pdfinfo $FILE_NAME.pdf | grep 'Page rot:' | cut -d":" -f2)

if [ $X -eq 0 ] || [ $X -eq 180 ] ;
    then echo "portrait"
    pdftk $FILE_NAME.pdf cat 1-endright output sortie-0.pdf
    else echo "landscape"
    cp $FILE_NAME.pdf sortie-0.pdf
fi

echo '\documentclass[a4paper]{article}' > sortie-1.tex
echo '\usepackage{pdfpages}' >> sortie-1.tex
echo '\begin{document}' >> sortie-1.tex
echo "\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2]{sortie-0.pdf}" >> sortie-1.tex
echo '\end{document}' >> sortie-1.tex

pdflatex sortie-1.tex 

mv sortie-1.pdf "${FILE_NAME}-Sortie.pdf"
rm sortie-*
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this doesn't behave any differently than my command line for me. It doesn't rotate individual pages.

Comment: Then i don't understand what you exactlty want.

Comment: I want all pages to have a portrait orientation, regardless of their orientation in the original document. So the brute force approach would be to split the document into individual pages, detect their orientation, rotate them 90 degrees anti-clockwise when they are in landscape, cat them back together again and 2-up them. I'm hoping there is a much easier way, though.

Comment: Lets try again ! ;-)

Comment: Ok, I seem to struggle to make myself cleary. I added a MWE to my question, including pictures. Pictures always help, right? :)

Comment: Sorry I"m not very good at english. Could you upload uour bad file where I can find it. Thank's.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'd rather not share my original document at this point in time. However, if you just build the MWE I added to the question with `pdflatex`, you should have a good toy example that contains all that's necessary.

Comment: Ok I didn't unerstood that the MWE build a pytholgic file, sorry. I'll see that tomoroow. I don't expect you give me one of your secret documents ;-)

Comment: `pdfinfo` doesn't give rotation information for your fill as it did for the files I worked with, then my strategy in more valable. One quick possibility is to open for pdf with `pdfshuffler`, rotate the pages you want and save as a new file then apply print procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If it works with `lscape` for printing, why don't use such a script for printing version :

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'

cat $1 | sed "s/pdflscape/lscape/g" > Sortie-0.tex
pdflatex Sortie-0.tex
pdfnup --paper a4paper Sortie-0.pdf -o Sortie-1.pdf
rm Sortie-0*
```